# Couldn't find a `pages` directory with Next.js and customer server build

Tags: node.js, docker, next.js

I'm currently trying to create a two stage build for an application that runs with Next.js (version 12.0.6) and has a custom server for an API. I do not want to rebuild the app each single time docker runs so I copy the compiled files into the /app directory. I'd assume that the pages directory would work automatically from .next folder but unfortunately it doesn't.

While the app builds all fine, I am plagued by this issue:

```
Error: > Couldn't find a `pages` directory. Please create one under the project root
    at Object.findPagesDir (/app/node_modules/next/dist/lib/find-pages-dir.js:33:11)
    at /app/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:113:45
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/app/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:74:20)
    at async Object.build [as default] (/app/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:82:25)
```

My Docker file looks like this:

```
FROM node:lts-slim AS base
WORKDIR /base
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .

FROM base AS build
ENV NODE_ENV=production
WORKDIR /build
COPY --from=base /base ./

CMD mkdir ./pages
RUN npm run build

FROM node:lts-slim AS production

ENV NODE_ENV=production
WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=build /build/next.config.js ./
COPY --from=build /build/package*.json ./
COPY --from=build /build/.next ./.next
COPY --from=build /build/public ./public
COPY --from=build /build/dist ./dist

# RUN mkdir pages; < uncommenting this will silence the error but it's an empty fake directory

RUN npm install
EXPOSE 3000

CMD npm run start
```

I start the Next.js sever like this (also tried with hardcoded false for the dev property with no success):

```js
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
const app = next({ dev });
```

And the npm commands in the project are as follows:

```json
 "scripts": {
    "prestart": "next build",
    "dev": "NODE_ENV=development ts-node --project tsconfig.server.json server/index.ts",
    "next-dev": "next dev",
    "build:server": "tsc --project tsconfig.server.json",
    "build:next": "next build",
    "build": "npm run build:next && npm run build:server",
    "next-start": "next start",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production node ./dist/server/index.js",
    "test": "jest"
  },
```

Things I have tried so far:

- Fiddling with the dir directory when creating the server. Unfortunately it seems to be correct by default pointing to the /app directly and changing it doesn't help
- Fiddling with the distDir in next.config. Unfortunately the same result as above
- Creating an empty *pages* folder in /app. This doesn't seem to work - pages are loaded from that folder and since there is nothing inside everything yields 404.
- Copying the entire *build* into *app*. While this creates pages folder and works, it completely defeats the purpose of a multi-stage build.
- Copying only pages folder. This fails miserably as it has dependencies on all of the other folders.

Could anyone please direct me on how to tackle this? I simply ran out of ideas and hopefully I'm missing something silly here.

Thanks!

Comment: What about simlink? . Create a link from the existing `pages` folder which should point on desired location? . And the other thing, If you do not need the `pages` directory, Do you use `nextjs` correctly?? . If you don't need it resp. do not have bad sideeffects, create that empty folder and that's it $

Comment: Hey Silvan, thanks for your answer! The symlink was a pretty good idea but unfortunately doesn't work as well. Somehow the next server is trying to recompile the app again on the start. Empty folder solution will not work as well - it simply returns 404 for all of the pages (they're actually needed it's just that the server cannot locate them).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering this myself as I got it to "work" and it might help someone else.

For a reason which seems to be beyond my understanding, creating a separate run script in package.json stopped Next.js to recompile itself whenever the app starts.

To reiterate on the steps taken:

- Using *npm start* caused the entire solution to recompile.
- Creating a new run line in package.json (I called it *npm run go*) prevents this from happens. Server spins up perfectly from the compiled js files and runs immediatelly.

It works but I have no idea why. If anyone has any insight I'm more than happy to hear it!